# How to evaluate bounds by converting to polar coordinates?

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

My question is only in regards to bounds of the following: [image: double integral]
I am trying to switch between polar coordinates and so using x=rcos(0) and y=rsin(0); however, the large source of my confusion lies in what the new bounds becomes. This integral will eventually use a u-substitution (and I'll get something like[image: u-sub]) then I can evaluate it before taking it's second integral, but how do I evaluate the changing bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tell my students to draw a picture of the  region.  Don't try to find the limits algebraically.    The region in the original integral is a quarter circle of radius 3, which is pretty easy to set up in polar.

Comment: Thanks @B.Goddard drawing a picture makes the most sense.